# GPG error: http://archive.cronical.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn valid, got 'NoDATA'

Tags: updates, internet, software-sources, gnupg

I'm getting this error when I try to update ubuntu 14.04:

```
GPG error: http://archive.cronical.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I found out it is due to the Internet connection, but I can't find how to fix it. May it be the configuration? Any tip is very welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

"cronical" should be changed to "canonical".

Do the following in terminal:

```
sudo sed -i s/cronical/canonical/ /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I was now trying to fix that problem and had no idea.
But now I get
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Thank you!! I manage to solve my problem by changing manually the source.list file. It wasn't elegant but it worked!

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, please mark it as "accepted" (a mark on the left side).